# How can I access data created in one event from another event?

Tags: c#, events, parameters

I want to access obtain data created in the `Load` event in the `TextBox.TextChanged` event.

How do I do this?

```
private void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Instantiating DB Obj
    DataBaseConnection obtainData = new DataBaseConnection();

    //Filling dataset
    obtainData.passSqlCmdandFillDs = "select * from [tblLogin]";
}

private void txtDisplay_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Want to user obtainData here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `obtainData` outside of the `Login_Load` event so it's available in other methods.

```
DataBaseConnection obtainData;

private void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Instantiating DB Obj
    obtainData = new DataBaseConnection();

    //Filling dataset
    obtainData.passSqlCmdandFillDs = "select * from [tblLogin]";
}

private void txtDisplay_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (obtainData != null)
    {
        // Use obtainData here
    }
}
```